# Using $PWD with subprocess.Popen() results in a Docker error, works from shell

Tags: python, docker, subprocess

I want to run a docker command from python using the subprocess Popen:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    shlex.split(r'docker run -v $PWD:/data blang/latex pdflatex main.tex'),
    cwd=temp_dir, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate()
```

While the command from the terminal works perfect, this returns:

> (b'',
>    b'docker: Error response from daemon: create $PWD: "$PWD" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed.\nSee \'docker run --help\'.\n')

Comment: `shlex.split()` doesn't get you "real" shell behavior. Frankly, it's better not to use it.

Comment: ...`split()` takes away control over exactly how your arguments are split into words -- if you were parameterizing with a user-provided filename instead of `main.tex`, you wouldn't want `Name With Four Words.tex` to be split into four separate arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"$PWD"` is a shell expansion. If you don't have a shell (as with `shell=False`), it doesn't get expanded.

`'%s:/data' % os.getcwd()` is a Python expression which will have the same result as `"$PWD:/data"` in shell. Thus:

```
import os, subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ['docker', 'run',
     '-v', '%s:/data' % os.getcwd(),
     'blang/latex', 'pdflatex', 'main.tex'],
    cwd=temp_dir, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

It's important not to use `shlex.split()` in this case: If you did, and were in a directory with spaces in its name, each segment of that directory would become a separate argument.

Comment: cool and clear explanation, but now the main.tex file is not found; which is really in the `temp_dir` folder

Comment: Dunno -- I'd need to inspect locally (ie. have a reproducer) to know what's going on with that.

Comment: simple: because I use the `cwd` argument, I had to replace the `os.getcwd()` with `temp_dir` :) thanks-a-lot

Comment: You should really use `os.path.join()` instead of string templates.

Comment: @AaronDigulla, in the context of `docker -v`, `:` is not a path element but rather a separator between two separate paths (directory location on the host, and bind mount location within the container). As such, I'm not joining two path elements into a single path, so `os.path.join()` isn't appropriate here.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Thanks. I hope OP is not using Docker for Windows (CWD could be `C:\projects\...`)